# Grunt:stop grunt task if one of the task failed

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is there a way to stop grunt task to run basing on other task failures??does grunt maintain any flags of task which failed or passed??or is there a way to check task failures??

```
 grunt.registerTask('test',['karma-unit-test','e2e-protractor-test']);

 grunt.registerTask('build',['force:on','test','force:off','buildAritfacts']);
```

Currently i have continued the grunt process even after task 'test' had failures but i need to stop running next task 'buildAritfacts'.

for example,
1.run the grunt test task by --force
2.check if 'test' task has failed or not
3.if failed then don't run the grunt 'buildArtifacts' task.

Comment: Why are you trying to force anything here? Just don't force it, and it will stop on errors by default.

Comment: Grunt 'test' task has other task like unit-test and e2e test task.Task unit-test is karma and e2e2-test is a protractor.i want ot contiue the test even after they test case failed and stop the building artifacts after the test has run.Since i am using karma for unit testing as karma doesn't have option to continue task if the test case failed so i need to use --force to conitue to e2e test.